# WiringPi install using npm fails

Tags: raspbian, node.js, wiringpi

I'm having a hard time installing the `wiring-pi` node package. It fails on the step "Making wiring-pi ...", spaming the terminal with build errors.

If I clone and install wiring-pi manually as described [here](http://wiringpi.com/download-and-install/), it works just fine. Also, I could not find any incompatibilies on the official [repo](https://github.com/WiringPi/WiringPi-Node).

System:

- node v10.12.0
- npm 6.4.1
- Raspbian GNU/Linux 9.4 (stretch)
- Release: 9.4

Any suggestion what is wrong? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Exactly which package did you install? What errors do you get? Did you install the necessary prerequisites (if any)?

Comment: package `wiring-pi` (as I said?), errors are mostly spam (uploaded here: https://github.com/BernhardSchlegel/stackoverflow/blob/master/wiring-pi-errors), no prereqquisites (npm should take care of).

Comment: The 'spam' conntains 49 error msgs. Mostly ` error: ‘class v8::Object’ has no member named ‘ForceSet’`. Search suggests a node version compatibility issue.

Comment: I was suspecting a version problem, and tried to downgrade node - witouth success. And as I couldn't find any officlal compatibility list, I thought maybe the problem is elsewhere